# Application has stopped working in vs2012 desktop application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am developing a software which is in c# desktop application in vs2012. Now whenever I run the program at that time it show the title error i.e. **MultiPurpostAccountingSoftware(Application Name) has stopped working.**

For, more clear lets the image of that error 
[image]

I tried many of things but didnt success any thing. For Ex:

**1. I repair the vs2012**

**2. Delete this folder: %AppData%..\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0**

**3. Go to Tools->Import & Export Settings -> Choose Reset all settings**

**4. Try running Visual Studio as administrator**

**5. Open Visual Studio 2012, but don't load any solutions / projects
Open Extensions and Updates from the Tools menu
Disable Web Essentials 2012
Delete the .suo file for your solution
Open the solution in Visual Studio
See that it loads and Visual Studio doesn't crash
Enable Web Essentials 2012
Restart Visual Studio 2012 and reload your solution.**

**6. Download the Web Essentials 2012**

I tried this much of things but didnt work anything. Is there any other solution or I want to uninstall and install it only.

Comment: If you debug the program what happens? Where does the error occur? What is the error? Have you checked the event logs of the computer?

Comment: nothing happing just stuck the software. Then after that we want to close via task manager.